# Test ROM's in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to execute de system.img for the Nexus 4 that you can download from the developers google webpage (https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=es#occamjwr66y) with the Android Emulator. To do this, I have created an ADV with target 4.3, and I have executed the next command in my Ubuntu:

```
emulator -avd Nexus4 -system/Image_android/system.img
```

But the emulator doesn't start the system, it is always in a black screen. Is it possible to execute new ROM's in the emulator? In the case that the answer would be no, is there any alternative to test ROM's or kernels in some Android Emulator?